# Cannot execute PhantomJS on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04, phantomjs

Have been trying to install latest version (1.9.8) of phantomjs on Ubuntu 12.04 VM without success.
Here's what I did so far:

1. To get rid of old version, executed

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove phantomjs
   ```
2. To get rid of old symlinks, executed

   ```
   rm -r /.../phantomjs
   ```
3. Downloaded phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2.2 into /usr/local/share dir and extracted:

   ```
   sudo wget . . ..tar.bz2
   sudo tar xjf phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
   ```
4. Created new symlinks to /usr/local/share/, /usr/local/bin/ and /usr/bin

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs  /usr/. . ./phantomjs
   ```
5. Checked version:

   ```
   phantomjs --version
   ```

This is the message that is returned:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/phantomjs: cannot execute binary file
```

Could someone explain why this is happening and what to do to fix it?

Comment: You need to extract the phantomjs `.tar.bz2` tarball that you downloaded. It isn't the executable it is a tar-ed and compressed archive.

Comment: Just forgot to document that.  That was actuall my 4th step:  
    sudo tar xjf phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

Comment: Are you running an `x86_64` machine? Or are you running an `i386`/etc. machine?

Comment: running an x86_64 vm

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.8-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs` say?

Comment: It says it's an executable

Comment: What does it say exactly? What are the permissions on the file?

Comment: That's all `file` says? What about the permimssions?

Comment: Yes, also changed permissions somewhere in the midst of the above:
    sudo chmod +x phantomjs
Shows up in file settings as:
Owner: Read and write, Group: Read-only, Others: Read-only
Execute: Allow executing file as program

Comment: Other execute but not owner execute is odd but if you got it sorted out by installing through npm that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Was given suggestion to use npm to install:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Had problems:

```
. . . 
nodejs is already the newest version. 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or 
if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Was informed that simple `apt-get install nodejs` installs npm as well, so tried that, followed by

```
sudo npm -g install phantomjs
```

Finally:

```
... 
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs phantomjs@1.9.12
 /usr/lib/node_modules/phantomjs 
├── which@1.0.8
├── progress@1.1.8
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── ncp@1.0.1 ├── kew@0.4.0
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── request-progress@0.3.1 (throttleit@0.0.2)
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── npmconf@2.0.9 (uid-number@0.0.5, inherits@2.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, ini@1.3.2, once@1.3.1, 
      config-chain@1.1.8, semver@4.1.0, nopt@3.0.1) 
└── request@2.42.0 (caseless@0.6.0, json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, 
forever-agent@0.5.2, stringstream@0.0.4, oauth-sign@0.4.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.0, qs@1.2.2, 
node-uuid@1.4.2, mime-types@1.0.2, http-signature@0.10.0, form-data@0.1.4, bl@0.9.3, hawk@1.1.1, 
tough-cookie@0.12.1)
```

Checked version:

```
sudo phantomjs --version 
1.9.8
```

As final proof of it being installed and working, re-ran previously failing cucumber tests (couldn't pass because phantomjs was missing), and all cucumber tests dependent on phantomjs now pass

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue then I followed following things for the usage

**Step-1**

First go to http://phantomjs.org/download.html
and download zip file for your system version which match 32-bit or 64-bit

**Step-2**

Extract Downloaded zip file

**Step-3**

Open Terminal Then reach to extracted folder then it will have bin folder

**Step-4**

Run the below Command

```
 > sudo cp phantomjs /bin
```

After that run phantomjs command

```
> phantomjs -v
2.1.1
```